# Linq - where condition on child table

Tags: c#, linq

can we apply where condition on a column in child table in below query ?

Patient is main table and i need to supplement below where condition with a column in Assess table like

```
Where(a => a.Date >= startdate && a.Date < stopdate && a.patient.assess.column1 == 10)
```

---

full query

```
  => dc.Patient
        .Include("first")
        .Select(a => new
        {
            Patient = a,
        Date = a.Assess.Max(x => x.Date),
        M3 = a.M3,
        Assess = a.Assess,
        Details = a.Assess
                    .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Key,
            x.Team
            })
        })
        .Where(a => a.Date >= startdate && a.Date < stopdate)
        .OrderBy(a => a.Date)
        .Take(batchSize)
        .ToList()
    );
```

Comment: Is the relationship one to many? What if one of the children has value 10 and another child has value 20? Do you want to include the parent in the query?

Comment: If you just want any child to have the value 10, you can use the following condition: `a.Assess.Any(x => x.column1 == 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use additional sub/embedded lambda statements within a lambda. In this case the [IEnumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) statement can be referenced inside the Where statement. Any will return `true` if there is any condition that matches the lambda and can be called as `Assess` is a collection.

My assumptions were:

- `Assess` is a strongly typed collection
- You wanted any the `Where` clause to match if there were any `Assess` instances in the collection where the property `column` was equal to the value of `10`

Code:

```
=> dc.Patient
    .Include("first")
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Patient = a,
        Date = a.Assess.Max(x => x.Date),
        M3 = a.M3,
        Assess = a.Assess,
        Details = a.Assess.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Key,
            x.Team
        })
    })
    .Where(a => a.Date >= startdate && a.Date < stopdate && a.Assess.Any(ass => ass.column1 == 10))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Date)
    .Take(batchSize)
    .ToList()
);
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. Appreciated.

Comment: @chint - glad it helped. Also if there is an answer to your question that you feel was the best one or the one that helped you the most please mark it as answer using the check mark next to that answer (the check will then turn green). You can only mark 1 answer as the "correct" in each question.